# Error Iteration with Django in template two variables in same time

Tags: python, html, css, django

I want to iterate two lists in one loop, and I am getting this error.

```
<ul> 
{% for protein, ligand in protein_list, ligand_list %}
    
  <li> {{protein, ligand}} </li>

{% endfor %}

</ul>
```

```
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\Narsil\dev\django-project\templates\RMSD\main.html, error at line 10

'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for protein, ligand in protein_list, ligand_list
```

Comment: Why not zip them and then iterate through them?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, and it work.